# Logging into forum via urllib2, missing params?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

Looking for some help regarding this python script I wrote to log into this forum.

```
import urllib2, re
import urllib, re

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
logindata = urllib.urlencode({'Username': 'x', 'Password': 'y'})
response = opener.open("http://www.sythe.org/login.php?do=login", logindata)

file_ = open('response.html', 'w')
file_.write(response.read())
file_.close()
```

I would appreciate any feedback anyone could give me about why this is not working. It seems as though it isnt even logging in at all? Is there an extra parameter I am missing in my login data?

EDIT: Used fiddler to look at the http post, looks like the password becomes encoded (I did not remove the password out from this picture)
http://puu.sh/lMXih/74dd43862c.png

Comment: I have had problems in the past with urlencode.  I take the result of the urlencode, and then re-encode it with the params encoding='uft_8' and errors='strict'  This is was it looks like    `param_string = urllib.urlencode(param_dict)`    
    `param = param_string.encode(encoding='utf_8', errors='strict')`

Comment: Interesting! that didn't seem to be the issue but it makes sense to do it that way in the future if you've run into problems with the base urlencode by itself

Comment: FYI Try requests library - It makes task likes this easier http://docs.python-requests.org/